# importing public key with GNU Privacy Assistant (win 10)

Tags: encryption, gnupg, public-key, private-key, kleopatra

I am trying to import my public key that I generated with Kleopatra and GNU Privacy Assistant.

First I generated my public and private keys. I then export my public key and save it to my desktop (Windows 10). So, let's say my public key is saved as `shaun_pub_key` I then add the `.pgp` extension so that my public key is saved on my desktop as `shaun_pub_key.pgp`. I then want to import the key to GNU PA Key Manager, but even though it reads the file as a public key it does not import it.

When i try to import the public key this is what it says..

```
1 public key read
0 public keys imported 
1 public key unchanged
```

I have tried importing the key with Kleopatra and GNU Privacy Assistant and both give me the same thing... `1 public key read and 0 imported`.

Can anyone tell me what  am doing wrong?